# parse timespan to string c#

Tags: c#, sql

I got stuck on converting `timespan`, in sql server jamulai column datatype is `time`

```
private void btntambah_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int kodejadwal = Int32.Parse(txtkode.Text);
    string hari = txthari.Text;
    TimeSpan jamulai = new TimeSpan (txtjam.Text);
    string jamselesai = txtjam2.Text;

    this.jadwalPraktekTableAdapter.Insert(hari, jamulai, jamselesai);
    this.jadwalPraktekTableAdapter.Fill(healthy_CareDataSet.JadwalPraktek);
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you converting Timespan to or from string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TimeSpan ToString format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077711/timespan-tostring-format)

Comment: string to timespan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Please read documentation for `TimeSpan`: [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ecy8h51(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. And custom `TimeSpan` to string formatting : [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx)

Simply follow the documentation of `TimeSpan` and put in the format that you require.

Answer (score 2):

To convert a timespan to string you can just use `timespan.ToString()`

In your case you need `jamulai.ToString()`

To format the timespan to suit MySQL's time formatting you need to do this:

```
jamulai.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss")
```