# Standard TimeSpan format for notation like 1d, 3y, 30s...?

Tags: .net, serialization, timespan

I am coming from .NET world so that why I am using TimeSpan term for defining time period or time duration. I am wondering if is any "standard" which define time period like following:

- 1h
- 1s
- 1h3m5ms
- 1y3d (i know it can already be problem here with converting it to seconds, but still)

I saw something similar in InfluxDB (https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/data-types/basic/duration/) and I am implemented my own implementation if it, but this is so common I am wondering about standard. Why not serialization like is implemented in TimeSpan (e.g. 6 days: `6.00:00:00`). Because it is harder to read.

I know this question is similar to [TimeSpan ToString format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077711/timespan-tostring-format), but my wish is less verbose.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unclear what you're asking for, but if you are looking for *any* standard for duration formats then you can use the `Period` object from [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org/) to work with [ISO 8601 Durations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations), such as `P1Y3D`.

If you're looking specifically for the format you described - that's some nice human-readable output, but it's not any standard I am aware of.